# Как в Unity выводить камеру с андроида в портретном режиме?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, android-camera

[image: Нужно как на этой картинке, чтобы справа снизу была камера пользователя]

Помогите решить проблему с камерой, хочу сделать возможным использования камеры в моём приложении, я пытался использовать юнитековскую Web Camera Texture, но она работает странно, выводит камеру в перевернутом положении (лендскейпе), а нужно в портретной. Как мне это лучше всего реализовать?

Comment: А при чем тут Unity? Берите Xamarin/MAUI, там этого добра полно.

Comment: @aepot Потому-что я использую юнити как движок

Comment: Как движок игры? Вам нужна камера в игре? Тогда почему на весь экран? А потом, что мешает текустуру повернуть на 90 градусов? И ещё нюанс, вы говорите, что выводит как перевернутую, но на скриншоте выглядит всё нормально.

Comment: @aepot Я пытался, максимум что выходило, так это перевернутое изображение, вроде бы черных полос нет, но изображение выводиться некорректно, если объяснять прям по простому, то подбородок у тебя будет слева, глаза справа.

Comment: @aepot скриншот это какой мне нужен результат

Comment: Так покажите, что вы пытались сделать и как и что получилось.

Comment: @aepot Только что решил проблему, просто используя маску. Не нужны части сами скрываются.

Comment: Как закрыть тему?)

Comment: Можете удалить вопрос, либо написать исчерпывающий ответ, а затем принять его как решение.

Comment: Благодарю) Всего доброго!

Answer (score 0):

Только что решил проблему, просто используя маску. Не нужны части сами скрываются.

Comment: Этот ответ ничего не объясняет будущим посетителям. Дополните его всей необходимой информацией, чтобы другие участники могли разобраться, в чем дело.